# I search a tutorial on how play and customize with collection form

Tags: forms, collections, symfony, label, customization

I need to create some forms non-linked to entities.
I pretty understood how create my builders, but when I try to use them, I am pretty confuse, and I don't really find examples in the online doc of Symfony 2.0

To go into the details: I create a "Multiple choice question" form. So I created:

- a "class ResponseType extends AbstractType"
- a "class MCQType extends AbstractType", which uses my class ResponseType
- a file "forms.html.twig", which includes templates for my "responsetype_widget" and for my "mcqtype_widget"

My aim is to be able to customize the labels and play with them in this template (like add div with uniqueID, etc), specially the itemization when I add a new item: I would know how to change the "0", "1", "2", etc in "Bad answer 1", "Bad answer 2", etc.
Currently, I do it with JQuery, in the client-side. But when I submit my form, and an error appears, my created items appear with the "0", "1" ; generated by the server-side.

Here are screenshot to have a better view of the situation:

- [Modified by JQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmul1.png) (sorry not enought reputation to post images)
- [Generated by Symfony 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Lr9o.png)

I really would customize these labels on the server-side, or in my "class MCQType extends AbstractType", or from the mcqtype_widget in forms.html.twig

I tried a lot of stuff that I found in the doc, but nothing works and I feel desesperate to mofify that from the JS instead of the server-side.
Is somebody have a good example?

Thank you by advance. And if any good tutorial is realeased about manipulate collections, I would really help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do for customizing those labels is to redefine the template block to include your modification.

To do so, you'll need this part of the documentation : 
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

I would also advise you to play with that in order to get familiar with the form collection : 
http://bootstrap.mohrenweiserpartner.de/mopa/bootstrap/forms/collections

Don't hesitate to go deep inside to see how they are doing.

PS: if you need to hide those labels, you need to pass `'show_legend' => false,` inside the field options